# Outlook Filtering on Conversations

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to filter out all email messages in my Inbox view that are flagged, UNLESS it is in a conversation and NOT the latest message in that conversation.

The first part is simple enough with the Advanced, Query Builder, or SQL tab (NOT("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10900003" IS NULL)).

How do I determine whether it is the *latest* message in the conversation?

Comment: Please post your current code

Comment: There is no static condition that can satisfy that condition.